# I need js or jquery , html slider , one type of range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range

I try to found on internet but not found this kind of slider need help.
So, My question is need to make this slider or any already plugin or library is exist?

See below attachment :[image]

Comment: You could probably use slick slider, it's customizable.
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: I am talking about range slider. Above the audio element not slick or swiper

Answer (score 0):

Please try using jQuery Slider property. Here is the [jQuery slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) documentation.

Try to explore on the topic as you would find more examples on the internet.

Comment: It is advisable to give specific answers. Not just a bunch of links.

Comment: @Eddie, Thanks for it. I updated my answer to a relevant link.

Comment: What I meant is, when you answer, you provide **code**, **examples**, **explanation**. You **don't** just give a link/bunch of links and tell the OP to explore the link.